# How can i split text input to a list in C++?

Tags: c++, input, text, split

I can split a given text into a list, but it doesn't work if I want to split a string given by the user.

```
void removeDupWord(string str)
{
    string word = "";
    for (auto x : str)
    {
        if (x == ' ')
        {
            cout << word << endl;
            word = "";
        }
        else
        {
            word = word + x;
        }
    }
    cout << word << endl;
}

int main()
{
    string ss;
    cin >> ss;
    ss = "split this";
    removeDupWord(ss);
}
```

Comment: If you want to split a string given by the user, you should use `getline()`.  With your method, you get the first word only in string `ss`.

Comment: where should I put `getline()` ?

Comment: Insted of `cin >> s`, use `std::getline(std::cin, ss);`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Comment: you are making assumptions about your code that don't hold. You can use a debugger or print `ss` after reading it from the user to see where the actual issue is

Comment: OT: you shoud change `removeDupWord(string str)` to `removeDupWord(const string & str)` for efficiency reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead of `std::cin`. With `std::cin` the input after whitespace will be discarded.

```
int main()
{
    string ss;
    std::getline(std::cin, ss);
    //ss = "split this";
    removeDupWord(ss);
}
```

Also, you should use C++ standard algorithm for such trivial task

```
void removeDupWord(const std::string& str)
                 // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Noice this change
{
    std::stringstream ss(str);
   
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>{ss}, 
              std::istream_iterator<std::string>{},
              std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

<kbd>[Demo Here](https://rextester.com/XMAJ57894)</kbd>

Comment: @P0W Why are you writing "std::istream_iterator<std::string>{}" as 2nd parameter to ````std::copy````? A simple "{}" would be sufficient. Like ````std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(ss), 
              {}, std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));````